# How to stroke SVG elements together, as a single element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

Lets say we have an SVG, containing a group with two elements, like the example code in the `<g>` element docs at [mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g).

In that case they apply a stroke on the group, and it is applied individually, like this:

[image: Two Circles with stroke on both individually]

But I want the stroke to be applied to the elements combined like that:

[image: Two circles with stroke, but no stroke where they overlap]

I'm using React to render the SVG as JSX, that might narrow the available options somewhat...

Thanks!

Comment: draw 3 circles, the 2 with a green stroke and then another white circle without a stroke located at the position of either of the other circles.

Comment: You are probably better off manipulating the circles as suggested with 3 circles above.  I did try replicating the shape with 2 arcs plus a line in between: `<path d="M34.5 64.5 a25 25 0 1 1 30 -30 l1 1a25 25 0 1 1 -30 30z" stroke="pink" stroke-width="5" fill="white" opacity="50%"/>` over the shape in the example given. It works but no idea how effective it is to other radiuses and joined at different points. But my initial idea was you have 2 arcs that are joined by a diagonal (unseen).

Comment: The problem with merging the two shapes is that it destroys any patterns inside the shape. my use case includes a shape inside a shape, a clipping mask will destroy that pattern.
The other solutions work only in this example exactly, for more difficult paths, it will be really hard to manipulate the shapes like you're suggesting....

Comment: While a `mask` will remove the inner pattern, the `clipPath` should preserve it...